# $f| _{dense\;set}=0$ and continuous on lines $\implies f \equiv 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Denoting $I=[0,1]$, let $f:I^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f=0$ on a dense set $A \subseteq I^2$, i.e. $cl(A)=I^2$.

Assume also that $f$ is continuous on horizontal and vertical lines, i.e. $\forall x_0,y_0 \in I: f(x,y_0) \in C(I),f(x_0,y) \in C(I)$.

Prove that $f$ is identically $0$.

Comment: 2 upvotes without showing any work? This site is awfully generous today.

Comment: @AlecTeal I think this is a very difficult and interesting problem, so I’m actually wondering why there are _only_ two upvotes. Indeed, three out of the four answers below have been deleted because they were based on an oversimplifying interpretation of the problem, and even the fourth answer by Nicolas has been edited abundantly and needed to make an extra assumption!

Comment: Where did you get this question from ? Did you make it up or did you find it in a textbook ?

Comment: Please answer my question, if it comes from a textbook maybe there are hints there, if you made it up then it is useful to know that maybe a counterexample exists.

Comment: No counterexample should exist, yet the source of this question provides no hints.

Comment: What is the source ? You seem very mysterious about it^^

Comment: A talented friend who refuses  to give hints. Though he did say that the proof is not as 'global' as one might suppose.

Comment: Ok, I think I found a proof that is posted below. Tell your friend his problem is awesome !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawing a picture next to this proof makes it much more clear (as with many proofs...)

Choose any $(a,b)\in [0,1]^{2}$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

By density of $\{f=0\}$ there is $(x_{1},y_{1})\in (a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\times(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon)$ such that $f(x_{1},y_{1})=0$. By continuity on vertical lines there is $\delta_{1}$ such that $f(x_{1},y)<1/2$ for $|y-y_{1}|<\delta_{1}$, and we can take $\delta_{1}$ such that $\delta_{1}<1/2$ and $[y_{1}-\delta_{1},y_{1}+\delta_{1}]\subset (b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon)$.

Now repeat the construction recursively for each $n$ to find $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ and $\delta_{n+1}$ such that

- $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \in (a-\delta_{n},a+\delta_{n})\times(y_{n}-\delta_{n},y_{n}+\delta_{n})$
- $\delta_{n+1}<1/2^{n+1}$
- $[y_{n+1}-\delta_{n+1},y_{n+1}+\delta_{n+1}]\subset (y_{n}-\delta_{n},y_{n}+\delta_{n})$
- $f(x_{n+1},y)<1/2^{n+1}$ for $|y-y_{n+1}|<\delta_{n+1}$

The constructed sequences have the following properties:

- $\delta_{n}\rightarrow 0$
- $x_{n}\rightarrow a$ (because $\delta_{n}\rightarrow 0$)
- $y_{n}$ has a limit $\bar{y}\in [a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon]$, which is the unique element of $\bigcap_{n} [y_{n}-\delta_{n},y_{n}+\delta_{n}]$.
- $f(x_{n},\bar{y})\leqslant 1/2^{n}$ so that $f(a,\bar{y})=0$ by continuity on horizontal lines.

We have shown that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $\bar{y}$ such that $f(a,\bar{y})=0$ and $|\bar{y}-b|<\varepsilon$. By continuity on vertical lines $f(a,b)=0$. Since $a,b$ were arbitrary, $f=0$.

Comment: Wow! Finally, a complete answer! Brilliant! +1

Comment: That's beautiful :)
By the way, $\bar{y}\in [b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon]$. (edit<6 characters)

Answer (score 4):

**NOTIFICATION :** this answer is valid for an uniform continuity on the lines, *i.e.* the below $\delta_x,\delta_y$ are independant of the choice of the horizontal/vertical line.

Let $(x,y)\in I^2\setminus A$ and $\varepsilon>0$. By hypothesis, there exist $\delta_x,\delta_y>0$ such that
$$|x-x_0|<\delta_x\Longrightarrow|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|<\varepsilon/2\quad\quad\forall y\in I$$
and
$$|y-y_0|<\delta_y\Longrightarrow|f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon/2\quad\quad\forall x_0\in I.$$
Now, as $A$ is a dense set, we can find $(x_0,y_0)\in A$ such that
$$|x-x_0|<\delta_x,\quad |y-y_0|<\delta_y.$$
Then we have
$$|f(x,y)|=|f(x,y)-\underbrace{f(x_0,y_0)}_{=0}|\leq|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|+|f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon$$

As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we've shown that $f(x,y)=0$. As $(x,y)\in I^2\setminus A$ was arbitrary, we've shwon that $f$ is identically zero on $I^2\setminus A$.

Comment: This proof needs a little improvement. Note that the choice of the $\delta$ that satisfies $|y - y_0| < \frac{\delta}{2} \rightarrow |f(x_0, y) - f(x_0, y_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ in general depends on your choice of $x_0$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out this fact ; however, I think what I've written is fine : I did not precised for what choice of $\delta(\varepsilon)=\delta(\varepsilon,y,x_0)$ we have the inequalities with $\varepsilon/2$. We know that we can find such $\delta$ due to the hypothesis of continuity on $f$ on the lines. Now, to write it more in details, what you've said is a good point to consider.

Comment: @Nicolas I'm afraid this construction gives rise to circularity: the choice of $(x_0,y_0)$ depends on $\delta$, and the choice of $\delta$ depends on $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: @triple_sec I do not see where... Here what I was thinking about : we have $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|<\varepsilon/2$ if $|x-x_0|<\delta(\varepsilon,x,y)$ by continuity on the horizontal lines, and also $|f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|<\varepsilon/2$ if $|y-y_0|<\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y)$ by continuity on the vertical lines. What do you think about this argument ?

Comment: EDIT: it is true that we must fix $x_0$ first before choosing $\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y)$, but I do not see any problem with that...

Comment: @Nicolas If you fix $x_0$ before choosing $\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y)$, how do you know it will be sufficiently close to $x$?

Comment: @triple_sec $x_0$ is chosen in the interval $]x-\delta(\varepsilon,x,y),x+\delta(\varepsilon,x,y))[$. The continuity of $f$ on the horizontal line $[0,1]\times\{y\}$ tells us that we can do that. Now $x_0$ is fixed. On the vertical line ${x_0}\times[0,1]$, $f$ is continuous, so  we can choose $y_0$ on the interval $]y-\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y),y+\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y))[$. Here, the dependance on $x_0$ is not very important : it tells us that we are on the vertical line ${x_0}\times[0,1]$ ; the continuity on this line tells us that, when $x_0$ is fixed, if $y_0$ is close enough of $y$, [...]

Comment: [...] then we have $|f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)|$ small. The OP tells us that $f$ is continuous on every vertical lines, so who is $x_0$ here is not very important for the choice of $y_0$. What is important however is that the density of $A$ allows us to choose $y_0$ in $A$.

Comment: @Nicolas If $x_0$ is chosen arbitrarily in the interval $(x-\delta(\varepsilon,x,y),x+\delta(\varepsilon,x,y))$, it is not guaranteed that $\{x_0\}\times[0,1]$ will contain a point in $A$, despite the fact that $A$ is dense—it is _a fortiori_ not guaranteed that one can choose $y_0$ in such a way that both (i) $(x_0,y_0)\in A$; and (ii) $y_0\in(y-\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y),y+\delta(\varepsilon,x_0,y))$.

Comment: @triple_sec Oh yes, you're right for this point : indeed, $A$ does not intersect necessarily with the line ${x_0}\times[0,1]$ ! So there is something in more to say. Anyway, the long discussions since I've posted this answer let me think that I had to modify it. So I will as soon as possible, thanks!

Comment: Edited. I have a doubt now about the OP : does $f$ is uniformly continuous for all lines ? I mean, is the $\delta_y$ the same for every vertical line $\{x'\}\times[0,1]$, $x'\in[0,1]$ ? I treat it like this as it was my original understanding of the question.

Comment: I saw your edit. I'm worried that one cannot guarantee that the constant of continuity $\delta_x$ will be the same for _every_ $y\in I$. Indeed, for any fixed $x\in I$ and $y\in I$, there exists some $\delta_x^y>0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta_x^y\Rightarrow|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)|<\varepsilon/2,$$ but this constant $\delta_x^y$ may vary with $y$ in an unpredictable way! I've been thinking a lot about this myself, and I'm now at a point of doubting whether the claim is true...

Comment: So we posted at the same time: yes, I'm afraid that the uniformity of the $\delta$’s is _not_ guaranteed.

Comment: Ok, I will notice this important point in my answer. Thank you anyway for your comments!

Comment: The uniform continuity assumption you added after this discussion actually makes $f$ continuous...

Comment: @Sergio And the conclusion is the well known result that a continuous function that is identically zero on a dense set is identically zero everywhere!

Comment: Indeed, and what you wrote in your answer is more or less a proof of that well known result :) But the original question is only interesting for functions that aren't continous...